# URL containing non-visual characters

Tags: url, unicode, web, special-characters, web-crawler

My crawler engine seems to have a problem with a specific customer's site.

At that site, there are redirects to URLs that look like this:

`http://example.com/dir/aaa$0081 aaa.php`
(Showing the URL as non-encoded, with $0081 being two bytes represented using HEX.)

Now, this is when inspecting the buffer returned after using the WinInet Windows API call HttpQueryInfo, so the two bytes actually represent a WideChar at this point.

Now, I can see that e.g. $0081 is a non-visual control character:
[Latin-1 Supplement (Unicode block)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29)

The problem is that if I use the URL "as-is" (URL encoded) for future requests to the server, it responds with 400 or 404. (On the other hand, is it removed entirely, it works and the server delivers the correct page and response...)

I suspect that FireFox/IE/etc. is stripping non-visible controls characters in URLs before making the HTTP requests... (At least IEHTTPHeaders and FF Live HTTP Headers addins don't show any non-visible characters.)

I was wondering if anyone can point to a standard for this? For what I can see non-visible chracters should not be found in URLs, so I am thinking a solution might be (in this and future cases) that I remove these. But it is not a topic that seems widely discussed on the net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example given, $0081 is just five Ascii characters. But if you mean that this is just what it *looks* like and you have (somehow) inferred that the actual URL contains U+0081, then what should happen, and does happen at least on Firefox, is that it is %-encoded (“URL encoded”) as %C2%81 (formed by %-encoding the two bytes of the UTF-8 encoded form of U+0081. Firefox shows this as empty in its address bar, since U+0081 is control character, but the server actually gets %C2%81 and must take it from there.

I have no idea of where the space comes from, but a URL must not contain a space, except as %-encoded (%20).

The relevant standard is Internet-standard [STD 66](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/std/std66.txt), *URI Generic Syntax*. (Currently RFC 3986. Beware: people still often refer to older RFCs as “standard” in this issue.)

Comment: I have expanded my original question to clarify certain things. I will try later with Ethereal to prove/disprove my point. (If I am correct that FF/IE is simply removing the invisible control characters completely.) When viewing HTTP Live headers, it simply is not there, URL encoded or not. (But if you are correct, then that only leaves the possibility that the server behaves differently depending on the crawler/user agent/HTTP-request-headers.)

Thanks for your answer, I will return with results of my upcming Ethereal analysis :)

Comment: Testing with `<a href="http://www.google.fi/?q=a&#x81;b">link</a>` I can see that U+0081 gets transferred. Using Tamper Data in Firefox, i can see that the request gets properly encoded as GET /?q=a%C2%81b

Comment: I am going to accept your answer. Thanks for your help :) (The general cause for my problem with this specific website/behavior remain elusive to me though. Many odd things. Both WinInet and another HTTP library I have tried receives a 301 redirect for a specific percentage-encoded URL, but the same percentage-encoded URL entered into FF, even duplicating the request headers, does not. It is spinning my head. I will open a new question if I get anywhere near enough understanding to ask it.)

Comment: In the end, I found the solution to my problem by identifying the underlying problem (non percentage encoded UTF-8 chracters in 301 redirect location header) and asking more precisely here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487341/can-wininet-httpqueryinfo-return-raw-bytes-http-headers-with-unicode-character