# Can WinInet HttpQueryInfo return raw bytes? (HTTP Headers with unicode characters)

Tags: delphi, unicode, header, delphi-xe2, wininet

The built-in routine HttpQueryInfo returns a string, not actual bytes. Normally that is not a problem.

However, lately I have begin to encounter a problem with servers issuing redirects where the location header field contains an URL which includes non-percentage-encoded unicode/or? characters. Any way around this?

```
        var
          vContent_Wide: WideString;
        begin 
          vBufferSize := 4096;
          GetMem(vBufferPtr, vBufferSize);
          while True do
          begin
            TmpFakeCardinal := 0;
            vErrorNone := HttpQueryInfo(
              hHttpOpen_Request,
              HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF,
              vBufferPtr,
              vBufferSize,
              TmpFakeCardinal
            );
            if (vErrorNone = False) then
              begin
                vErrorID := GetLastError;
                if (vErrorID = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) then
                  begin
                    FreeMem(vBufferPtr);
                    GetMem(vBufferPtr, vBufferSize);
                  end
                else Break;
              end
            else
              begin
                vContent_Wide := PWideChar(vBufferPtr); 
                Result := vContent_Wide;
                Break;
              end
            ;
          end;
          FreeMem(vBufferPtr, vBufferSize);
```

Comment: Please edit your question: add the tag of certain Delphi version you use. It is not clear if you call HttpQueryInfoA or HttpQueryInfoW

Comment: What is vContent_Native? Whatr is msxCopyPCharToStr ? You show no declarations!

Comment: The comment in the code shows it. Delphi 2007 maps it to HttpQueryInfoA and Delphi XE2 (all unicode versions) maps it to  HttpQueryInfoW. (and vContent_Native is the corresponding string type)

Comment: But I have corrected the code now to assume Delphi XE2. (But the problem exists in both "A" and "W" versions of the API call. I have experimented quite a bit back and forth)

Comment: AFAIU HTTP specs, the servers should negotiate either in Latin1 charset or at least in UTF-8. If u use AnsiString and HttpQueryInfoA - what is the binary content u get there ? what is exactly the problem for you ? would functions like System.UTF8ToString or System.Utf8ToAnsi help ?

Comment: HttpQueryInfoA returns the HTTP headers as a buffer of bytes containing Ansi/codepage characters. HttpQueryInfoW returns the HTTP headers as stream of bytes containing wide characters. However, the problem is exactly the same in both cases :) Some of the characters don't show up correctly. I believe the cause is that there are unicode characters in the HTTP header response where WinInet API assumes the HTTP header response is US-Ascii (or at least assumes it is something which it is not.)

Comment: (The point being the API call has already tried to convert the stream of bytes to either Ansi/codepage or Wide. But it has not done so correctly. That is why I want access to the raw bytes, so I can write my own code)

Comment: you can try to look at original stream by few methods: 1) route your app traffic via special proxy, like Membrane Monitor; 2) use tcp dumper like WireShark or TDI Dump to sniff all the traffic; 3) try connecting those URLs with some other tool showing (at least optionally in some config) HTTP traffic, like wget, ReGet Personal, LiveHeaders for Mozilla, Fiddler for MSIE. // when you say "don't show up correctly" - are they all replaced with some same for all pre-defined char ? or what ? u have examples ?

Comment: BTW, if WinInet HTTP fails you - why not use pure Delphi HTTP libraries ? Like Synapse or Indy ? Frankly, you can just open TCP stream and put there HTTP command directly - it is not hard. Run *cmd.exe /k telnet.exe google.com 80*, key in *GET /* {ENTER} *Host: google.com* {ENTER} {ENTER} - and here is your 1st manual HTTP request

Comment: Indy fails as well resulting in strings containing "??" replacement characters. Anyhow, my question is: Is there any WinInet API flag/call I am missing that would allow me to grab the raw bytes? (Again, both WinInet and Indy works with thousands of sites I have seen, both unicode and non unicode URLs, but they both appear to fail if the HTTP response 301 location header contains non-percentage-encoded unicode characters in the redirected-to URL)

Comment: Indy's `TIdHTTP` component uses the `IOHandler.DefStringEncoding` property to decide which charset to use for decoding HTTP headers. You can set the `DefStringEncoding` property before sending a request if you want to use a different decoding charset.

Comment: Both Synapse and Indy are opensource. You can easily hook into the place between raw TCP client and HTTP client and set breakpoint before the transcoding piece. However dunno if those probably buggy servers are worth it.

Comment: Would it not be safe to set Indy/Http to default to UTF-8 instead of US-ASCII? Or is here any situation where this might not be advisable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URIs do not support unencoded Unicode characters. If the server is sending a non-percent-encoded Unicode string in the `Location` header then the server is buggy and needs to be fixed as this is a clear violation of [RFC 2616 section 14.30](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30).  My guess is that the server is actually sending an unmapped IRI ([RFC 3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987)) instead of a URI ([RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)).  HTTP does not support direct use of IRIs, they have to be mapped to URIs ([RFC 3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987) defines how to do that).

With that said, check if setting the `dwInfoLevel` parameter to `HTTP_QUERY_CUSTOM` allows `HttpQueryInfo()` to return the raw bytes of the header or not.  If not, then you will not be able to use WinInet for those servers that are failing, as there are no other functions in the WinInet API that can access HTTP headers.  You will have to find another HTTP library that supports what you need, or else you can drop down to the TCP/IP layer and implement the HTTP protocol manually in your own code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Remy. I have upvoted it now, I expect to mark is as accepted answer later tonight or tomorrow :)

Comment: I did not succeed with HTTP_QUERY_CUSTOM, but I am testing out your comments regarding Indy now.

Comment: The solution ended up being what you suggested elsewhere in a comment: Set Indy's TIdHTTP IOHandler.DefStringEncoding to UTF-8. This solved the problem for two separate customers